# Let G be an abelian group. Suppose $a, b$ are elements of orders $m$ and $n.$ Let $d =\operatorname{lcm}(m, n).$ Show that $(ab)^d = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Here are my thoughts so far:
G is abelian so $ab = ba.$

For $d = mn, (ab)^{mn} = abab..ab = aaaa..bbb$  as abelian $= a^{mn}b^{mn} = e$ as $a^m = e$  and $b^n = e.$

For $d< mn,$ let $d = qm$ and $d = pn.$ Then
$$\begin{align}(ab)^{qm} &= a^{qm}b^{qm} \\& = eb^{qm} \\&= b^{qm}\\
  (ab)^{pn} &= a^{pn}b^{pn} \\& = a^{pn}e \\&= a^{pn}\end{align}$$
so $b^{qm} = a^{pn}$ so $a^d = b^d.$

I'm not really sure how to continue from here/ if this is even the logically path I should be following

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when $G$ is abelian, we have that $(ab)^d=a^db^d=a^{qm}b^{pn}=(a^m)^q(b^n)^p=e^qe^p=e\cdot e=e$.